# How to multiple two cell when i input number and text in same time in those cell in excel

Tags: excel, ms-office

I want to multiple two cell. I input number and text in same time in those cell. Like, Cell A1 input "20 kg" and cell B1 input "30 kg". Now how can multiple A1 and B1 in C1 cell.

[image: My problem image here]

Comment: Are the measurements the same or do you need to convert.  It would be better if you would put the labels in another column instead into the same cell.

Comment: The text kg is always the same or it can vary?

Comment: Why would you multiply kilograms?

Comment: The text kg is always same @  Daniel Labbe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the cell number formatting to custom with `0\k\g` and retype *20* and *30* into A1:C1.

`=A1*B1` will show `600kg` in C1.

Comment: I guess other custom number formats would have to be created. It's hard to tell what other formats would be necessary from the question. I think the main point is to keep numbers as numbers instead of trying to repair them after changing them to text unnecessarily.

Comment: @Md.MehediHassan - select A1:C1 then tap ctrl+1. On the Number tab, choose Custom from the list down the left side and put `0\k\g` as the Type.

Answer (score 0):

In **C1** enter:

```
=numpart(A1)*numpart(B1)
```

where `Numpart()` if this user defined function:

```
Public Function NumPart(r As Range) As Double
    Dim s As String, t As String, L As Long, i As Long
    Dim CH As String

    s = r.Text
    L = Len(s)
    For i = 1 To L
        CH = Mid(s, i, 1)
        If CH Like "[0-9]" Then
            t = t & CH
        End If
    Next i

    NumPart = CDbl(t)
    If Left(s, 1) = "-" Then NumPart = -NumPart
End Function
```

[image]